# Path component should be '/'

Tags: java, path, filesystems, uri

I'm trying to create a `FileSystem` object to hold an ext2 filesystem. My `URI` seems to be invalid, giving me a **path component should be '/'** run time error.

I'm using Windows and have my project in Eclipse, with a subdirectory called "fs" that holds the filesystem image.

My code...

```
URI uri = URI.create("file:/C:/Users/Rosetta/workspace/filesystemProject/fs/ext2");
/* uri holds the path to the ext2 file system itself */         

try {
    FileSystem ext2fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, null);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    /* ... code */
}
```

I have loaded the filesystem as a `File` object and used the `getURI` method to make sure my `URI` is the same as the actual `URI`, and it is.

How can I get the filesystem loaded?

EDIT:

Stack trace below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path component should be '/'
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.checkUri(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: have you tried `file://` (which is the protocol) in front of the path '/C:/...', thus making `file:///C:/...`?

Comment: Changing that gave me the exact same error :(

Comment: what about adding `/` to the end of the URI? If ext2 is the mount point, i'd expect it to need a path after it, so `file:/C:/Users/Rosetta/workspace/filesystemProject/fs/ext2/`

Comment: Same error again. ext2 is the actual filesystem image. This is infuriating!

Answer (score 14):

The WindowsFileSystemProvider's checks that the URI's path is only '/'. The uri is perfectly valid as URI, the problem is the FileSystem's requisites. crashystar has it right (I can't comment yet) and a Path should be used.
If you read the JavaDoc of newFileSystem(Path, ClassLoader) you'll see the ClassLoader can be left at null, so you just need to do

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:/Users/Rosetta/workspace/filesystemProject/fs/ext2");
FileSystem ext2fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(path, null);
```

By leaving it at null Java tries to locate an installed provider (so you could not expect a custom provider to be used). If it were a custom provider you'd have to use a ClassLoader that can load that provider. If the provider is on your classpath, it'd be enough to do

```
getClass().getClassLoader()
```

Since you say you just want the OS to do that, leave it at null.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me on Windows. Haven't tested it out in other OS yet

```
 private void openZip(File runFile) throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
    env.put("create", "true");
    env.put("encoding", "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(runFile.toURI());
    Files.deleteIfExists(runFile.toPath());
    zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI.create("jar:" + runFile.toURI().toString()), env);
    //zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(runFile.toPath(), getClass().getClassLoader()); //-----does not work 
    //zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI.create("jar:file:/c:/Users/Siraj/Documents/AAAExport4.zip"), env);  //---works  
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Why not use a Path object?

```
newFileSystem(Path path, ClassLoader loader)
Constructs a new FileSystem to access the contents of a file as a file system.
```

Note the three constructors:

```
static FileSystem   newFileSystem(Path path, ClassLoader loader)
Constructs a new FileSystem to access the contents of a file as a file system.

static FileSystem   newFileSystem(URI uri, Map<String,?> env)
Constructs a new file system that is identified by a URI

static FileSystem   newFileSystem(URI uri, Map<String,?> env, ClassLoader loader)
Constructs a new file system that is identified by a URI
```

Comment: I tried this at first however I have no idea what a `ClassLoader` is or how to use one. How do I use a `ClassLoader` with the first method to get a `FileSystem`?

Comment: This leads to the question, what's the difference between getFileSystem() and newFileSystem()?  One would think newFileSystem() creates a brand new blank filesystem.... Otherwise, why have a getFileSystem()?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:/C:/Users/Rosetta/workspace/filesystemProject/fs/ext2");
```

Comment: I found this helpful because my Uri is used to extract a jar-file. I don't know what happens when a zipFileSystem is opened on a normal folder.