# IllegalArgumentException: Path component should be '/' while using Zip File System Provider

Tags: java, file, zip

I'm trying to copy the contents of different folders into a zip file I just created. I read on this forum that I could use ZipFileSystemProvider since java 7 but I can't do it.

I tried in different ways but each time I had errors: https://hasteb.in/wiqefaje.md
https://hasteb.in/ireduxef.md

It is not a duplicate of : [Path component should be '/'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078996/path-component-should-be)
because the solution they give is not working in this case (I cant to create a zipfile)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Path component should be '/'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078996/path-component-should-be)

Comment: Here is what I get using this solution: https://hasteb.in/unabukep.js

Comment: Coul it be an error in creating the zip file? I couldn't reproduce the error using some random zip file I had lying around. The line that throws the exception for you executes for me.

Comment: Yes this is because using that way it cannot create the zip while with the other it should. How would you create a zip file then?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413379/java-nio-zipfilesystem-zip-end-header-not-found-while-creating-file-system
not sure if the solution in this thread is valid to you, since it doesn't allow you to add to an existing zip file, but apparently creating a new one helps. If you're just writing into an empty zip, that could help.